# Support multiple languages with localized strings in a JSP/Servlet and HTML5/JavaScript Web Application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, localization

I have a web dynamic project written using the JSP/Servlet framework, with client-side in HTML5/CSS and JavaScript. This means the server-side programming language is Java (standard or inside the scriptlet for JSP pages), while the client-side one is JavaScript.

I need a way to manage strings translated for multiple languages (e.g. English, Italian, Spanish, French...), that have to be used according to the language used by the user (i.e. language of the browser). I could do this by defining a list of strings for each language, e.g. using an XML file for each languages, as the following example:

```
<!-- File: en-US.xml -->
<list lang="en-US">
    <string>
        <key>hello</key>
        <value>Hello!</value>
    </string>
</list>

<!-- File: es-ES.xml -->
<list lang="es-ES">
    <string>
        <key>hello</key>
        <value>¡Hola!</value>
    </string>
</list>

<!-- File: it-IT.xml -->
<list lang="it-IT">
    <string>
        <key>hello</key>
        <value>Ciao!</value>
    </string>
</list>
```

In this way, I could use that file from JavaScript or JSP/Servlet, and get the strings.
This probably means I need two methods: the first one to be used in the server-side (Servlet and JSP), and the second one to be used in the client-side. But I'm not sure that there isn't a unique way to do this.

My questions are:

- What is the best way to manage localized strings in a JSP/Servlet/JavaScript web application? Are there some predefined methos, which take advantages of some APIs?
- Is there a way to do this by defining strings in a single file for each language, and use them both from JSP/Servlet and JavaScript?

Comment: Is using JSTL `<fmt:message>` with property files for language translations an option ?

Comment: I don't know any options, I need to know which options are available. Is you who have to tell me how to do! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whatever technique you want on server side. You can have xml files as you stated or you can use standard i18n included in java basing on ResourceBundle. In this case you create properties file for each language (refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html to see how to do this).

Now in java/servlet you first read the locales the browser sent you by accessing: request.getLocales (
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocales%28%29)

Having the locales used in browser, in java/servlet you read translations in "standard" way, so in case of ResourceBundle you do it like this

```
Locale locale = getLocaleBasingOnRequest(HttpServletRequest request); // read the locale sent by browser by accesing request.getLocales()

ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Translations_file", locale);
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(key);
  System.out.println(bundle.getString(key));
}
```

Now to have the same translations in javascript you can output the translations to javascript file dynamically. You can for example create TranslationsServlet which outputs the javascript translations to javascript array.

```
public class TranslationServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {


      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          Locale locale = getLocaleBasingOnRequest(HttpServletRequest request); // read the locale sent by browser by accesing request.getLocales()

          ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Translations_file", locale); // get the tranlation strings

          resp.getWriter().println("var translations = new Object();");
          for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
              resp.getWriter().println("translations[\"" + key + "\"] = \"" +   bundle.getString(key) + "\";");
          }

      }
}
```

above servlet should dynamically generate javascript file with translations, so it should output something like:

```
var translations = new Object();
translations["key1"] = "Test";
translations["key2"] = "Test2";
```

Having this dynamic translations you can include them in your every html page by simply adding javascript script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/translations-servlet" />
```

After this you get access to translations array in your javascript code, so you can simply access them by code like this:

```
for(var key in translations)
{
  document.write("for " + key + " the tranlations is " + translations[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to use [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) on server side. You simply put all your language translation files in same directory in classpath, for example `/org/example/nls/ihm.properties` (`Locale.ROOT`) `/org/example/nls/ihm_fr.properties` (`Locale.FRENCH`) `/org/example/nls/ihm_de.properties` (`Locale.GERMAN`)

The common way to keep the locale is to store it name in a session attribute, say `LOCALE`

Then you can access them easily from a servlet :

```
String localeName = request.getSession().getAttribute("LOCALE");
if (localeName == null) { localeName = Locale.ROOT; }
Locale locale = new Locale(request.getSession);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.sba.nls.ihm", locale);
String cancel = bundle.getString("CANCEL"); // gives Annuler (value from ihm_fr)
```

If you ask for a locale for which you do not provide a translation, you will end up using the JVM default locale. My advice would be to  have `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);` somewhere in your initialization code to ensure you will use `ihm` for an unknown locale.

It is almost as easy from a JSP file with JSTL :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<jsp:useBean id="LOCALE" scope="session" class="java.lang.String"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${LOCALE}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="org.example.nls.ihm" var ="ihm"/>
...
<fmt:setBundle basename="org.sba.nls.ihm" var ="ihm"/>
<fmt:message key="CANCEL" bundle="${ihm}"/>
```

Of course, as the translation files are on server side, you cannot use them directly on client side javascript. But you can easily use a JSP to generate a JSON String containing useful translations :

```
<%@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="LOCALE" scope="session" class="java.lang.String"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${LOCALE}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="org.sba.nls.ihm" var ="ihm"/>
{ CANCEL: <fmt:message key="CANCEL" bundle="${ihm}"/> }
```

You can then get it from client side javascript and use it for your translations